# angular $http make form submit file fail

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, upload, submit

here is my code:
html:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' name='biosUpload' method='POST' action='partials/uploadComplete.html' target='hiddenFrame' >
  <input type='file' name={{romName}} id='brwsUpld'  />
</form>
<button type="button"  ng-click="uploadFwImage()">upload</button>
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" frameborder="0"  iframe-upload  id="uploadIframe"></iframe>
```

note: uploadComplete.html just a html without code.

js-controller:

```
$scope.iframeFlag = false;

//submit form in $http's promise won't upload the file,
//just load uploadComplete.html into iframe, 
//but when submit form outside the $http's promise ,it works.
//the problem is code follows worked ago, but just yesterday I found it can't , I am so confused. 

//way1:
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'rpc/test.asp'
}).
success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.iframeFlag = true;
        document.forms["biosUpload"].submit();
}).
error(function(data, status) {});

//way2:
document.forms["biosUpload"].submit();
```

js-directive:

```
define(['./module'], function (directives) {
    'use strict';
    directives.directive('iframeUpload', function(){
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('load', function (event) {
           console.log(scope.iframeFlag);
          if(scope.isStop)return;
          if(!scope.iframeFlag)return;
            scope.uploadComplete();

        });
    };
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link : linkFn
    };
  });
});
```

question:
 when way1 mode, it just load uploadComplete.html into iframe.
 when way2 mode, it also transfer the file to webserver successfully.
 why $http will affect load() mechanism.
 Actually, way1 worked ago, just yesterday it failed, and never worked again.

Comment: try with $document maybe you overwrite document somewhere else

Comment: could you give me more detial?

Comment: you can inject the document in the controllers or directives http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$document and if i remember well you can also have the form passed to the controller by name maybe is a proper solution http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem.
the submit button just do submit action.
ajax request are done before that action.
I haven't found the reason $http affect submit with file ever.
If you know the reason, no mercy your answer.